# Create an OS X today widget without a host app

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, today-extension

Is it possible to create an OS X Yosemite Today Widget without a host app, like the builtin Weather, Stocks and World Clock apps?

Comment: I don't think you can do it

Comment: So even if all the UI and functionalities are in the today widget, I'll still need to create a "blank" host app for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that simply because your executable is still running in the companion app rather in the extension. It means that codes are actually belonged to the companion app. So, you must have your companion app.

Info from the official documentation:

> An app extension is different from an app. Although you must use an
>   app to contain and deliver your extensions, each extension is a
>   separate binary that runs independent of the app used to deliver it.